# Division by 0 in pandas -Avoid it

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({f'Diff (a - b)': c['a'] - c['b'],
'Diff in %': (c['a'] - c['b']) * 100 / c['a']})
```

If some value in c['a'] will be 0 it will not be correct to divide by 0.
Overall function doesn't fail, and outputs `inf` for these cases.

How to avoid this situation and instead of `inf` add 0 for these cases (when c['a'] == 0)?

Comment: 'c' is a dict or a dataframe?

Comment: c is Dataframe import pandas as pd

a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [4, 5, 6]

c = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})

df = pd.DataFrame({'col21': (c['a'] - c['b']) * 100 / c['a']})

Comment: col21
0 ->   -inf
1 -> -400.0
2 -> -200.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can replace `np.inf` by 0 with `replace` method:

```
a = [0, 1, 2]
b = [4, 5, 6]
c = pd.DataFrame({'a': a, 'b': b})
df = pd.DataFrame({'col21': (c['a'] - c['b']) * 100 / c['a']})

df = df.replace({-np.inf: 0})
print(df)

# Output
   col21
0    0.0
1 -400.0
2 -200.0
```